# DTrace on Leopard: No probes specified, even when I specify probes

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, dtrace

```
% sudo dtrace -p 2446 'objc$target:NSObject:-init:entry { trace(); }'
dtrace: no probes specified
```

[The manpage](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man1/dtrace.1.html) suggests that this is the correct format with which to specify a probe on an Objective-C method. I tried -Z, but (unsurprisingly) that just didn't print anything.

[Added] It's not even specific to Objective-C probes. I tried it with a C function from AppKit:

```
sudo dtrace -p 2446 'pid$target::NSPopAutoreleasePool:entry { trace(); }'
dtrace: no probes specified
```

So what's wrong? Why does DTrace think I have not specified any probes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you mean:

```
sudo dtrace -p 2446 -n 'objc$target:NSObject:-init:entry { trace(); }'
```

Answer (score 0):

Does the process in question allow dtrace? Apple [doesn't always allow](http://blogs.oracle.com/ahl/entry/mac_os_x_and_the) dtrace on os x.

Comment: As far as I know, yes. It's an open-source app I work on, not anything by Apple, and I'm not aware of zsh setting `P_LNOATTACH` on my own processes.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Graham said, your original statement will only find instances of NSObject, not its descendents.  You could try

```
sudo dtrace -p 2446 -n 'objc$target::-init*:entry {}'
```

to catch all -init variants by all NSObject-derived instances.

Comment: It wouldn't catch the `[super init]` message by a subclass?

Comment: I don't think so.  It's my impression that the module is always set to be the instance's class, even when it's calling a method via super.  I just tried the command line I suggested with NSObject instead of a blank module and got no matching probes, while leaving the module out hits ~3400 on the application I tried.